Who Are the Actors in the Fictional TV Series, Darkness At Noon?
During the fifth season of the television series, The Good Wife, the series introduces an in-verse TV series with a saterical stint towards AMC late-night cable series featuring a celebration of antiheroes in comparison to shows like Breaking Bad or The Walking Dead. It's titled, Darkness at Noon. (There is even a "Talking at Noon" aftershow)
From there on out Darkness at Noon reoccurs on the series, as Alicia seems to be invested the series, despite it also often becomes background noise. My question is, Who are any of the real life actors playing these Darkness at Noon characters?








